# Ubuntu 12.04 cannot detect my second screen

Tags: xorg, multiple-monitors, monitor

What I wanted is a dual monitor setup but I got two monitors with the same content :(.

I have an ASUS [Z87-K](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/Z87K) motherboard and am connecting two monitors to its integrated graphics (HDMI and VGA). I installed Ubuntu 12.04. Both monitors were showing me a mirrored screen. The option in "monitor" settings to untick "mirror" is disabled. Display setting shows that there is only one monitor or Ubuntu thinks there is only one monitor. I have gone through all posts to get my latest xorg intel video drivers. Strangely, my monitor was detected as laptop screen.

Do you have any similar experiences? How did you resolve it?

Here's some basic information:

```
~$ xrandr
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 640 x 480, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 1920 x 1080
default connected 1920x1080+0+0 0mm x 0mm
1920x1080       0.0* 
1280x1024       0.0  
1024x768        0.0  
800x600         0.0  
640x480         0.0  

~$ lspci -k|grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
```

Comment: I've searched on the internet. It seems there plenty of people who had this issue with Intel HD graphics driver.

Comment: I have gone around with this problem after a few days of struggling with it. I bought an in-expensive graphics card. ASUS Z87-K motherboard supports up to two PCI-e graphics and supports three monitors. It is felt that nvidia graphics are supported in ubuntu community than Intel HD graphics. Although Windows 7 supports dural screen without additional effort, a second graphics from nvidia is considered a quick workaround at a monetary sacrifice.

Comment: Back to square one, after updating some mysterious component.

Comment: back to square one, because I connect VGA to intel HD controller and HDMI to Nvidia card. It was temporarily doing dural display for one night. The second night, after some update in the display driver, all went to square one. Now, I just connected my VGA screen to VGA output of the nvidia card. All was fine